Can I list references in rmarkdown with html output showing a single word like "link" linking to the url instead of sowing the entire url?
I'm using rmarkdown (more specifically: bookdown) to create a webpage. The html book has many references, and I have a link for every reference to the file. I'm using apa.csl (from zotero) to format the refences, and use the 'url' field in my bibtex file to specify the links.
I would like, however, to just use a link like 'paper' or 'link'  to link to the url, instead of showing the entire url.
I tried to modify apa.csl to do this, but I'm not sure how (or whether that's even possible). The idea is that links show up as "link" or "pdf" which link to the url spceified in the url field, instead of showing the whole url and linking to it
I found this post for how to do this when compilingn to pdf with latex:
'Link'-button instead of complete URL in bibliography
Can I do something similar when I compile to html output?

@Fran I'm not sure in CSL it would be as easy as in markdown itself. However, the OP didn't provide anything to test with so it's hard to say.

@Marijn True.  I read quickly and didn't understand the question, although in any case is off-topic.

Thanks for your responses, I clarified the question, but not sure why it is off topic

@mchlmchl Markdown is off-topic because it is not LaTeX, and CSL is off-topic on its own as well because it is a citation system that is independent of LaTeX. It is on-topic to ask about conversion from and to LaTeX and using (packages for) non-standard workflows within your LaTeX document. So RMarkdown would be on-topic when it is about the LaTeX conversion, and CSL is on-topic when you call it using the citation-style-language package or using citeproc-lua, [...]

[...] but asking how to implement a feature in a CSL stylesheet would strictly speaking not be on-topic, even though this feature would need to output a LaTeX command.

In any case, I think it is ok to leave open, there are not so many people here that may be able to answer but only one if enough I guess :)
